# Screen brightness not changing on Acer 5742 notebook

Tags: 10.10, brightness

Screen brightness is not changing on my ACER 5742 notebook. I have Ubuntu 10.10 installed inside Windows 7 OS. Hotkeys are used for changing brightness. Though, a bar displaying brightness level appears on screen but there is no actual change in brightness of screen.

Answer (score 6):

This worked for me. Run:

```
gksu gedit /etc/default/grub
```

Change the line:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
```

Make it say this instead:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="acpi_osi=Linux"
```

Then run `sudo update-grub` and reboot. Credit to [this guy](http://livinginjava.blogspot.com/2010/11/ubuntu-1010-brightness-problem-in-acer.html).

Answer (score 1):

Modifying both these lines in `/etc/default/grub` worked for my 4810T:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_backlight=vendor"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="acpi_osi=Linux"
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with my Acer 5749.  The bar displaying the brightness would show that the brightness was moving up and down, but the actual brightness wasn't changing.

In `/etc/default/grub`, I tried just:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="acpi_osi=Linux"
```

But it didn't work. Then I tried:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_backlight=vendor"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="acpi_osi=Linux"
```

and that *did* work.

In both cases I edited the lines in `/etc/default/grub` then ran `sudo update-grub` and rebooted.

#### Another way, by editing just one line:

Finally I tried just:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_backlight=vendor"
```

and that worked too.  I put the other line back to how it was originally and the brightness control still works after running `sudo update-grub` and rebooting again:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
```

Comment: I'm glad I posted this because the hard drive failed and was replaced.  Now I need to fix the brightness problem again.  I'll try just editing the GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT line in /etc/default/grub and running 'sudo update-grub'.

Comment: That worked. . .