# Adjusting brightness on Dell Vostro 3500 won't work

Tags: 11.04, dell, brightness

On a fresh install of Ubuntu 11.04, running Unity, I can't adjust the brightness via Fn+Up/Down. The brightness panel will show, and increase/decrease accordingly, but the actual brightness never changes.

This is an issue I also had on 10.04. I used to fix this by adding this line

```
Option "RegistryDwords" "EnableBrightnessControl=1"
```

to my /etc/Xorg/xorg.conf in Section "Device". However it seems this is not working anymore. I also noticed the config file is much smaller that what I remember. Here is the whole file:

```
Section "Device"
Identifier      "Default Device"
    Option  "NoLogo"        "True"
    Option  "RegistryDwords"        "EnableBrightnessControl=1" 
EndSection
```

Should I use this line somewhere else ? or is there something else to fix ?

For reference, here is the original issue on 10.04: https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xserver-xorg-video-nv/+question/109012

Comment: Did you solve the problem? I've got the same on my 3500...

Comment: No, not solved. I'll post the answer if I find it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

i have same problem on dell vostro 3500 and solution from this question helped me to fix brightness bug: [Screen brightness not changing on Acer 5742 notebook](https://askubuntu.com/questions/21523/screen-brightness-not-changing-on-acer-5742-notebook)

The complete solution is:

1. edit /etc/Xorg/xorg.conf to add the
   following line in Section "Device":

   ```
   Option "RegistryDwords" "EnableBrightnessControl=1"
   ```
2. edit /etc/default/grub to change the
   line into:

   ```
   GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="acpi_osi=Linux"
   ```
3. run the command:

   ```
   sudo update-grub
   ```
4. reboot

Comment: It worked for me, however I had to re-add the line in my xorg.conf as described in the OP. Thank to everybody involved in this answer ;-)

Comment: It's still working for Ubuntu 11.10

Comment: It also works for Ubuntu 12.04 (Dell Inspiron 17R 7720; used "acpi_osi=" instead though but still worked)

Comment: Still working on 13.04 with one difference. There is no xorg.conf by default. To create one stop Xorg and run from root following commands:
`X -configure`
and then
cp /root/xorg.conf.new /etc/X11/xorg.conf

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to install Nvidia blacklight driver (`nvidia-bl-dkms`). The package itself has been developed for MacBooks, but they use same Nvidia model – G310M.

Comment: Sounds like a good idea, but unfortunately it didn't help at all, even after a reboot.
Another guy has similar result: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=10817972