# Brightness shortcuts don't work on on an Acer 4741

Tags: 11.10, brightness, bios

When I press Fn+Down and Fn+Up (the shortcuts for change brightness), it shows the indicator that the brightness has change, but its not change at real.

I've use this method

[Screen brightness not changing on Acer 5742 notebook](https://askubuntu.com/questions/21523/screen-brightness-not-changing-on-acer-5742-notebook/21526#21526)

After reboot, it just make the resolution down at 1024 x 768

Is it need to update BIOS?

Thanks, and sorry for my bad english

Comment: Did you run the last part of the command, 'sudo update-grub'? It worked on my Acer 5750.  Seems Acers have that issue right now.  I think it's probably a linux problem as I have the same problem no matter what distro I run.

Answer (score 1):

Please make sure that this is not a distribution-specific bug by trying other distros like Fedora, and by trying older versions of Ubuntu, like Maverick (10.10) I'm having similar problems with Oneiric, Natty and Fedora 15 on a computer where Maverick runs well.

Comment: Okay, thanks...
But this method is work at 11.04 too...
Then, Am I need to upgrade my BIOS?