# Brightness settings won't change on an HP dv7t-6100 CTO

Tags: 12.04, brightness

I recently installed Linux, and it seems my brightness settings will not change. I have keys on my laptop for it, and they lower and raise the brightness bar but the screen does not change brightness. Help?

Some specs: My laptop is a HP dv7t-6100 CTO. I have Linux Ubuntu 12.04 lts dualbooted with Windows 7. I can provide more if you need to know.

Comment: What Laptop, what Distribution...

Answer (score 1):

Do you have `acpi` enabled? If so, do you have a `/sys/class/backlight/` directory populated by folders named `acpi_videoX`, where `X` is some integer (normally `0` or `1`)? If you do, check whether the `brightness` and/or `actual_brightness` files within those folders have their contents changed when you attempt to alter the brightness level. You might also consider installing the `xbacklight` package and checking whether it works to change your brightness settings.

Comment: So, I didn't have acpi installed, but I installed it. I noticed no difference. I checked the folders (In that directory I have acpi_video0, acpi_video1, and intel_backlight), and each of the acpi_videoX folders have brightness and actual_brightness. They do change. At max brightness, each of the files say 10. After one press of the dim key, each of them go to 6 except the acpi_video0/brightness. It went to 8. I installed xbacklight and it didn't help either.

Comment: First, make sure `acpid` is actually running (`ps aux | grep acpid`). Then, try manually editing each of the individual `brightness` files in each of the sub-folders in the `/sys/class/backlight/` directory by altering the value to some different integer (less than the one specified in `max_brightness`). As soon as you save, the screen should dim appropriately if the file is indeed operative. If that doesn't yield any results, I'm afraid I'm out of ideas. Sorry.

Comment: You could also try the solution to a similar problem described [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/21523/screen-brightness-not-changing-on-acer-5742-notebook), if you haven't already.

Comment: No problem, all credit to the original poster of that solution. :)