# Acer aspire incompatible with ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: 12.04, installation, acer, aspire-one

Well I'm about to install ubuntu 12.04 on my laptop, which is an acer aspire. I would like to know if is there any incompatibility? I installed this version (12.04) on an acer aspire and had several troubles with the hardware drivers. 
I'll apreciate any help.
Thanks.

Comment: Thorough details of Model number is appreciated , also try here , if are interested in [problems](http://askubuntu.com/search?q=acer+aspire).

Answer (score 1):

I'm using an Acer Aspire 5742 and everything's fine. You may run into problems getting the brightness keys to work, along with the Webcam, but a quick google search should help you fix that.

Also, this related question should help with that:

- [Screen brightness not changing on Acer 5742 notebook](https://askubuntu.com/questions/21523/screen-brightness-not-changing-on-acer-5742-notebook)